# Jquery - Check CSS value

Tags: jquery, css

How can I check a value (from the CSS tag) with jQuery?

**CSS**

```
#my_div { display:none; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  if($('#my_div').is(':hidden'))
  {
     $('body').append('HIDDEN');   
  }
  else
  {
     $('body').append('VISIBLE');   
  }

}
```

This did not work. 
Hope somebody can help me.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9fSM6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis from `ready`: `);`

Also, put a `<div id="my_div"></div>` in your code, otherwise it will be handled as 'visible', because you have no 'my_div' element, so it is also not hidden.

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/ug6Dv/

Re-updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/PcmJW/

Comment: Ah - didn't spot that, that fixes problem.

Comment: Hi, this is my problem. This div doesnt exists in my code so i must check the css (direct). Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: I don't know if I unserstood what you mean by 'check the css', but if 'my_div' may not exist in the document, then check it using `$('#my_div').length`

Comment: @Peter new fiddle fork, using `length`

Answer (score 2):

Worked just fine for me when I added such `div` element: http://jsfiddle.net/9fSM6/3/

When you don't have any element, the `is()` will always return `undefined` so the `else` part will always be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You just could use `css` function. It return value of given css property:

```
$('#my_div').css('display')
```